# GridView Loads Slowly After setAdapter() Is Called

Tags: android, gridview

I have `GridView`s laid across my 3 page `ViewPager`. The idea is to build a monthly view of a calendar that scrolls infinitely as far as the user wants.

I based my work mostly off [Jon Willis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127422/jon-willis)' [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/app/HistoryMonthActivity.java) of infinite view paging. But instead of implementing my own `View` object; I'm using `GridView`s.

Here's my implementation of the `onPageScrollStateChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {     

        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) mMonthPager
                    .getAdapter();

            // Called to obtain reference for the Fragments inside the ViewPager.
        CalendarGridMonthlyFragment oldMinMonthFragment = (CalendarGridMonthlyFragment) adapter
                    .instantiateItem(mMonthPager, 0);
        CalendarGridMonthlyFragment oldMidMonthFragment = (CalendarGridMonthlyFragment) adapter
                    .instantiateItem(mMonthPager, 1);
        CalendarGridMonthlyFragment oldMaxMonthFragment = (CalendarGridMonthlyFragment) adapter
                    .instantiateItem(mMonthPager, 2);

            // Get the selected month for each Fragment.
        final Calendar oldMinMonth = oldMinMonthFragment.getSelectedMonth();
        final Calendar oldMidMonth = oldMidMonthFragment.getSelectedMonth();
        final Calendar oldMaxMonth = oldMaxMonthFragment.getSelectedMonth();

        if (mFocusedPage == 0) {

            final Calendar newMonth = (Calendar) oldMinMonth.clone();
            newMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

            oldMinMonthFragment.setSelectedMonth(newMonth);
            oldMidMonthFragment.setSelectedMonth(oldMinMonth);
            oldMaxMonthFragment.setSelectedMonth(oldMidMonth);

        } else if (mFocusedPage == 2) {

            final Calendar newMonth = (Calendar) oldMaxMonth.clone();
            newMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

            oldMinMonthFragment.setSelectedMonth(oldMidMonth);
            oldMidMonthFragment.setSelectedMonth(oldMaxMonth);
            oldMaxMonthFragment.setSelectedMonth(newMonth);
            }  

        mMonthPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
    }
}
```

And here's my `setSelectedMonth` method:

```
public void setSelectedMonth(Calendar value) {

    mMonth = value.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mYear = value.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    CalendarGridMonthlyAdapter newAdapter = new CalendarGridMonthlyAdapter(
            mContext, GRID_CHIP, mGridWidth, mGridHeight,
            mMonth, mYear);

    mGridView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
}
```

The infinite swiping works. But there's a noticeable flicker -- almost half a second -- after the scroll has finished.

Debugging has shown me that `setAdapter` method is the culprit of all this fuss. So is there any way to speed up the process of setting new adapter?

..or maybe another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use the same adapter instance, but change the month and year values?

Comment: I did tried that. But it made no changes to the views whatsoever. Even after calling the `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

Comment: I think you should use singleton Fragment pattern here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: I have the same problem. Even with a GridView of 3 items, the GridView animate slowly when setAdapter is called. I am wondering if that's an intended animation that can be disabled.